# Django 1.8 - Signals - What's the difference between @receiver decorator and Signal.connect() method?

Tags: python, django, signals, decorator, receiver

They appear to do the same thing. Is there a difference in functionality, usage, etc? In what circumstances should one be used over the other?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@receiver` is a thin wrapper around `Signal.connect()`. The only difference is that `@receiver` can accept not just a single signal, but also a `list` or `tuple` of signals, and it will connect the function to each of those signals.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py#L297), `@receiver` only calls `signal.connect(func)` and returns the original function.

Answer (score 4):

They indeed do exactly the same thing from a functional point of view. There is no reason to prefer the one over the other whatsoever, apart from how the developer wants to organize the code.

EDIT: As per the excellent answer from @knbk, you should use the `connect` function for specific actions, as for example to pass a list of callback functions.

From the [Django documentation on signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

> There are two ways you can connect a receiver to a signal. You can take the manual connect route:
>
> ```
> from django.core.signals import request_finished
>
> request_finished.connect(my_callback)
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use a receiver() decorator:
>
> ```
> from django.core.signals import request_finished
> from django.dispatch import receiver
>
> @receiver(request_finished)
> def my_callback(sender, **kwargs):
>     print("Request finished!")
> ```